# How do I always pull data from one table, but also pull data from a second table if it's there in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are my two tables:

**oasis**

```
+-----+-------+
| id  | title | 
+-------------+
| 234 |   a   | 
| 235 |   b   | 
| 236 |   c   | 
+-----+-------+
```

**user_collection**

```
+----+---------+----------+------+
| id | oasisid | username | data |
+--------------+----------+------+
| 1  |   234   |    joe   | blah |
| 2  |   235   |    bob   | blah |
| 3  |   236   |    ted   | blah |
+----+---------+----------+------+
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM oasis
JOIN user_collection ON oasis.id = user_collection.oasisid
WHERE username = 'greg'
AND oasis.id = '234'
```

What I want to do here is pull everything from **oasis** and **user_collection** that match, but also pull the information from **oasis** even if there is NO match on **user_collection**.

How do I fix my query to accomplish this?

Comment: Just make it `LEFT JOIN`.  http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  And you'll need to move your `USERNAME = 'greg'` to the on clause.

Comment: @Andrew You should put that comment as an answer; it solves the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left join`, but you have to be careful about the conditions in the `where` clause.  Conditions on the *second* table need to be in the `on` clause for the `left join` to work:

```
SELECT *
FROM oasis JOIN
     user_collection
     ON oasis.id = user_collection.oasisid and user_collection.username = 'greg'
WHERE oasis.id = '234';
```

Conditions on the *first* table should go in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the manual says, just to stick to MySQL...
"If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for the right table. You can use this fact to find rows in a table that have no counterpart in another table:

```
SELECT left_tbl.*
  FROM left_tbl LEFT JOIN right_tbl ON left_tbl.id = right_tbl.id
 WHERE right_tbl.id IS NULL;"
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

It also makes it clear, why to move the username criteria from the where clause to the ON clause, as Andrew says...

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT s.ome
      , c.olumns
   FROM table1 s
   LEFT 
   JOIN table2 c
     ON c.some_id = s.some_id
    AND c.some_column = 'one thing'
  WHERE s.some_other_column = 'another thing'
```